# Parsing XML from a SQL Server table column into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, reporting-services, xquery

SQL Server Standard 2017 on Windows Server 2019

I have a SQL Server table that contains an XML column to capture custom data

```
create table CustomerCrossReferences 
(
    customer BigInt, 
    product BigInt, 
    customColumns XML
)
```

The `customColumns` column contains XML data in the following format

```
insert into CustomerCrossReferences 
values (69731, 157,  
'<CustomColumnsCollection>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>MOI</Name>
    <DataType>0</DataType>
    <Value>10% max</Value>
  </CustomColumn>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>PRO</Name>
    <DataType>0</DataType>
    <Value>26% min</Value>
  </CustomColumn>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>FAT</Name>
    <DataType>0</DataType>
    <Value />
  </CustomColumn>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>WAT</Name>
    <DataType>0</DataType>
    <Value />
  </CustomColumn>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>FMT</Name>
    <DataType>0</DataType>
    <Value>None</Value>
  </CustomColumn>
</CustomColumnsCollection>')
```

I need to use this data to build a dataset in a report built in SQL Server Report Writer, selecting Value corresponding to the Name for the Customer/Product pairing. I won't be using DataType in the report.

At the moment I am thinking I should create a dataset in the following format to use in within my report structure

```
Customer    Product    Name   DataType   Value
-------------------------------------------------
69731       157        MOI    0          10% max
69731       157        PRO    0          26% min
69731       157        FAT    0          
69731       157        WAT    0          
69731       157        FMT    0
```

I can create this dataset with the following:

```
select
  customer
  ,product 
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/DataType)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
from
  CustomerCrossReferences
UNION ALL
select
  customer
  ,product 
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/Name)[2]', 'varchar(max)')
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/DataType)[2]', 'varchar(max)')
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/Value)[2]', 'varchar(max)')
from
  CustomerCrossReferences
UNION ALL
select
  customer
  ,product 
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/Name)[3]', 'varchar(max)')
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/DataType)[3]', 'varchar(max)')
  ,customColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/Value)[3]', 'varchar(max)')
from
  CustomerCrossReferences
```

While this works it will be cumbersome as I have approx 20 `CustomColumn` data elements to consider.

My question is whether there is a better way of handling this, either as a more concise/efficient query statement, or by being able to directly address the XML data within Report Builder. Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting tabular data in an XML column? That's what the table is for...

Comment: Not my choice. It's the mechanism that our ERP system uses to facilitate custom fields on certain programs. The user creates UDFs and there are stored in an XML field

Comment: Ah, ERP systems. I feel your pain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XQuery `nodes()` method to get your xml data in row format. something like:

```sql
SELECT  cc.customer, cc.product
,   n.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Name
,   n.value('(DataType/text())[1]', 'int') AS DataType
,   n.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Value
FROM    CustomerCrossReferences cc
CROSS APPLY customColumns.nodes('/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn') n(n)
```

Combined with `value()` method, you can retrieve individual elements of CustomColumn.

Comment: There is a significant performance improvement with the modifications I made.

Comment: Thanks @YitzhakKhabinsky, I believe you, but could you explain the reason for better perf? Or at least point me somewhere so i can learn :D

Comment: The easiest way to see it is to run both `SELECT ...` statements, yours and mine, in one query with the *Actual Execution Plan* setting on. You will the difference by comparing **Query cost (relative to the batch)** percentage.

Comment: And the reason for it is a peculiarity of the XQuery implementation in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Because `text()` pulls out the specific first inner text node, whereas not using it means you get an implicit conversion plus an extra lookup for all possible inner text nodes.